# Open Excel Office365 Doc with VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, office365, client-side

Have been developing with VB and Excel for some time using 2010 and 2016.   Recently my company moved to O365 and removed all of the PIA DLLs from our client machines.

Don't know if I am asking this correctly but I want to open/edit/create/save Excel Docs in O365 via a client-side VB.net app.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial, video, code snippet, etc.?

Also what References are required for the App to work.

Using VS2019.

- Sorry if this is typed or asked incorrectly.... long time listener, first time caller.

Comment: I would be looking to move to using oledb

Comment: OleDb?   That I never considered....  Can you use OleDB to access and write Excel docs in O365?    I am going to research that but it is an interesting suggestion.  - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved using Interops

With the 365 company was putting down 64Bit versions and my code wouldn't work.   De-installed Office365, Reinstalled Office365 but 32Bit versions and was able to get it to work.

Don't install the 2010 PIA.